# Windows Core Audio Error

Tags: windows, access-violation

I have the following function I am calling to print out the endpoint and friendly name of enumerated audio endpoints:

```
void EPPrint(void)
{       
    HRESULT hr;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDeviceCollection *pCollection = NULL;
    IMMDevice *pEp = NULL;
    IPropertyStore *pProps =NULL;
    UINT count;
    PWSTR strID;
    PROPVARIANT pv;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator ,NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, (void **)&pEnumerator);
    hr = pEnumerator -> EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender,DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE,&pCollection);
    hr = pCollection ->GetCount(&count);
    if(count==0)
    {
    }
    for (ULONG i =0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        hr= pCollection->Item(i,&pEp);
        hr = pEp ->GetId(&strID);
        hr = pEp ->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ,&pProps);
        PropVariantInit(&pv);
        hr = pProps ->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &pv);
        printf("Enpoint %d: \"%S\" (%S)\n",i,pv.pwszVal, strID);
    }
}
```

However I am getting runtime error `Unhandled exception at 0x008e104a in EPAudioControl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

which breaks the program at the `hr = pEnumeartor -> ...` line.

Does the program need some sort of special windows permissions in order to run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out pEnumerator was a NULL pointer. The `CoCreateInstance` call was not filling pEnumerator properly. This is becuase there must be a `CoInitialize(NULL)` call before CoCreateInstance. Once I put the `CoInitiliaze(NULL)` call into the program, the error went away.